# Postgresql Request wtith array_to_string

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, casting, request

Hello i am writting a pgsql function and inside this function , i have one request with array_to_string method.

```
    AND id NOT IN (array_to_string(excludeArcs,','))
```

ID is an integer but array_to_string return string so  :
Error result :
operator does not exist integer <> text

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is equivalent to `id NOT IN( '1,2,3' )`. You can not compare ID with string.

It is necessary to expand the array to the table:

```
AND id NOT IN(select * from unnest(excludeArcs))
```

Answer (score 0):

The transformation to string is wrong - string operation are more expensive

```
postgres=# select 10 = ANY(ARRAY[10,20,30]);
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ t        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select 10 <> ALL(ARRAY[10,20,30]);
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│ f        │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```